# Cordova iOS <a href="mailto:" and <a href="tel:" only working on long press

Tags: html, ios, xcode, cordova, mailto

I have two simple links in my app:

```
<a href="tel:00000000">Call 00000000</a>

<a href="mailto:service@xxx.com?subject=xxx"><i class="icon-envelope"></i><span data-string="email">Email</span></a>
```

And none of them works when clicked, only when long pressed.
They work fine when clicked on Android, Safari browser and when building and running the app in XCode to a device. **However it does NOT work after uploading the app to "Test Flight"**. I find this very strange...

In my config file I have added access origins:

```
    <access origin="*" />
    <access origin="tel:*" launch-external="yes" />
    <access origin="geo:*" launch-external="yes" />
    <access origin="mailto:*" launch-external="yes" />
    <access origin="sms:*" launch-external="yes" />
    <access origin="market:*" launch-external="yes" />
```

My version of **Cordova** is ***6.1.0***

And as mentioned it's only in test flight it's not responding on click event, I haven't published to prod(app store) because I have to be 100% sure this functionality works. Any one else having this problem ?

***The current version in app store works just fine, this version was published a month ago.***

Can it be that Apple has set restriction for this functionality, because someone misused the ***"tel:"*** to auto dial 911, and haven't informed developers about it ?

Comment: I just tried a new Cordova app created with CLI 6.4.0, cordova-ios 4.3.0 and tested on an iPod touch with iOS 9.3.5. Working fine as internal tester on testflight.

Comment: Okei, hmm... Thanks for the information :)

Answer (score 6):

It took me some time to figure out this "problem, but this works for me:

```
<a href="#" onclick="window.open('tel:00000000', '_system'); return false;">Call 00000000</a>
```

I also tried with window.location = "tel:00000000" but this didn't work.

So for now I guess I'll have to use ***window.open('tel:xxxxxxxx', '_system')***

Btw, if you want no redirection from current page set href to ->

`href="javascript:void(0);"`